# Obtaining the polynomial describing the motion

Tags: fitting

I have the following data points:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
dados={{0,0},{1,1000},{2,-750},{3,250},{4,-1000},{5,0}};
```

From these data I obtained the following interpolation:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
dados={{{0},0,0},{{1},1000,0},{{2},-750,0},{{3},250,0},{{4},-1000,0},{{5},0,0}};
Plot[Interpolation[dados][x],{x,0,5},ImageSize->500,Epilog->{Red,PointSize[0.01],Point@Partition[Flatten[dados],3][[All,1;;2]]}]
```

[image: Interpolation of data]

**Is it possible to get the polynomial that describes this movement?**

**Or is it unlikely due to the derivatives at the inflection points?**

As the `Interpolation function` used is it possible to "order" some polynomial?

**EDIT**

I added the `InterpolatingPolynomial function`, according to Szabolcs, but the function partially fulfilled what I wanted ...

```
Clear["Global`*"]
dados = {{{0}, 0, 0}, {{1}, 200, 0}, {{2}, -300, 0}, {{3}, 1000, 
    0}, {{4}, -800, 0}, {{5}, 0, 0}};
InterpolatingPolynomial[dados, t] // Simplify
Plot[%, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want `InterpolatingPolynomial`?

Comment: If you take a closer look `InterpolatingPolynomial` is among solutions provided for your last question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for the local polynoms between two successive datapoints:

```
Table[InterpolatingPolynomial[dados[[{i, i + 1}]], x], {i, 1,Length[dados] - 1}] 
(*{(1000 - 2000 (-1 + x)) x^2,
1000 + (-1750 + 3500 (-2 + x)) (-1 + x)^2, 
-750 + (1000 -2000 (-3 + x)) (-2 + x)^2, 
250 + (-1250 + 2500 (-4 + x)) (-3 + x)^2,
-1000 + (1000 -2000 (-5 + x)) (-4 + x)^2}*)
```

That's the list of cubic  polynoms (Hermite)!

**addenum  piecewise local polynomials**

```
Table[
Apply[Which, {dados[[i, 1]][[1]] <= x <= dados[[i + 1, 1]][[1]],InterpolatingPolynomial[dados[[{i, i + 1}]], x], True, 0}]
, {i, 1,Length[dados] - 1}];
Plot[%, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: I was just currently looking to use piecewise to plot. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
   Clear["Global`*"]
data = {{0, 0}, {1, 1000}, {2, -750}, {3, 250}, {4, -1000}, {5, 0}};
f[x_] := a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4 + a5 x^5
var = {a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};
nl = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[x], var, x];
Normal@nl
```

> 1.93616*10^-10 + 10833.3 x - 17270.8 x^2 + 9375. x^3 - 2104.17 x^4 + 
>    166.667 x^5

```
Show[Plot[nl[x], {x, 0, 5}], ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Here is LeastSquare Approach

```
MatrixForm[A = Coefficient[#, var] & /@ (f@data[[All, 1]])]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 \\
 1 & 3 & 9 & 27 & 81 & 243 \\
 1 & 4 & 16 & 64 & 256 & 1024 \\
 1 & 5 & 25 & 125 & 625 & 3125 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
b = data[[All, 2]]

LeastSquares[A, b] // N
```

> {0., 10833.3, -17270.8, 9375., -2104.17, 166.667}

If you want derivatives zero at each point and continuous poly then (note you are overfitting)

```
ip = 
 InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, {0, 0}}, {1, {1000, 0}}, {2, {-750, 
       0}}, {3, {250, 0}}, {4, {-1000, 0}}, {5, {0, 0}}}, x] // 
   Expand // N
```

> -29687.5 x^2 + 124693. x^3 - 202999. x^4 + 177321. x^5 - 
>    94396.7 x^6 + 32343.8 x^7 - 7210.07 x^8 + 1014.18 x^9 - 
>    81.8866 x^10 + 2.89352 x^11

```
 Show[Plot[ip, {x, 0, 5}], ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]